# How to stop a .bat process from within

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So, I have a program for the Windows Command Prompt, which is for changing the directory (so I can go to a language directory without having to do cd everytime)
and I want to kill it after I select an option. However, I have tried some
methods, which do one of the following:

**a.** taskkill /IM ... (blows up with a process not found error)

and

**b.** exit [*as shown here*] (does what I want, but it also closes the command prompt)

This is my program (the important part):

```
:C++
cd C:\Users\S.G.\Documents\C++ Scripts
echo What's in C++ Scripts:
dir
pause
exit

:Python
cd C:\Users\S.G.\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32
echo What's in Python:
dir
exit
```

The reason why I'm stuck as to how one does this is because say I choose option "C++".
If I choose it, it runs what I have described, but it also runs the "Python" function. If I run the "Python"function however, it runs fine and doesn't display whatever's in the "C++" function.

Why is function "C++" also running "Python" when I intend not to?

Comment: Try replacing `exit` with `goto :EOF`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `exit /b`, followed by an optional error code (eg. `exit /b 0`). An alternative way to do this is to skip to the end of the file using `GOTO:EOF`.